# Org-mode export to Latex error with footnotes

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

Whenever I write, in my `org-mode` file, `\footnote{bla bla bla $\whatever_{something}$}` I get an error in the `.tex` file generated.

What it exports to the `tex` file is `\footnote\\{bla bla bla \whatever_{something} \\\}` (note the lack of dollar signs),
which obviously is not compiled in the right way by latex.

However, if I remove the parentheses around the subscript, i.e.`\footnote{bla bla bla $\whatever_s$}`, then it is exported correctly.

*How can I fix the export?*

Comment: Try wrapping it in `#+begin_latex` .. `#+end_latex` or `#+begin_src latex` .. `#+end_src`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use org-mode's own built-in [footnote feature](http://orgmode.org/manual/Footnotes.html). The default binding to insert a footnote automatically is, <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>. Here is a MWE of an org-mode file that exports to LaTeX correctly, tested in org-mode v8.2.10.

```
A sentence[fn:1].

* Footnotes

[fn:1] bla bla bla $\whatever_{something}$
```